# Samba Share suddenly not accessible

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, smb

After looking for hours I'm looking for help here.

My Setup is:

- Server: Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS
- Client: Win 7 Verbindung mit Login des Unix Users

Yesterday SMB was working perfectly fine, but after coming home today, there is no connection to the shares.

My current user with ssh connects quite well and the server can be found on the client. But if I enter "root" -> "mnt" I'll get a permission denied...
Multimedia is working a little bit more, but only with those directly on the same drive. There are multiple symlinks which are not working.

Somebody help please :(

My SMB Config (Testparm looks good.)

```
[global]
workgroup = ZIRP
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)    
dns proxy = no
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0
;   bind interfaces only = yes
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n     *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
map to guest = bad user

[Home]
path = %H
comment = Home Directories
;   browseable = no
;   read only = yes
create mask = 0755
directory mask = 0755
;valid users = %S

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
   write list = root, @lpadmin

[Multimedia]
   path = /mnt/Festplatte2/Multimedia
   follow symlinks=yes

[Root]
    path = /
    valid users = benjamin
    write list = benjamin
    writable = yes
    follow symlinks=yes
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer myself on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1600541

Add the following lines to the [global] section of smb.conf:
Code:
    follow symlinks = yes
    wide links = yes
    unix extensions = no

Then restart the samba service:
Code:
    sudo service smbd restart